# What is $A'$ in the Reissner-Nordstrom metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, differentiation, notation, reissner-nordstrom-metric

So I was reading [this paper](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:912393/FULLTEXT01.pdf) on the Reissner-Nordstrom metric and on it they define $A$ as:

[image]

But they don't define $A'$. Yet $A'$ still ends up in other equations like defining the Ricci tensors:

[image]

So what is the equation to derive $A'$?

Answer (score 2):

$A'$ represents the derivative with respect to the radial coordinate $r$. See the beginning of page 27.

Comment: So is B' just 1/A' ?

Comment: No, see pages 28,30 and the begining of 31. The condition $B=1/A$ is solved from the $tt,rr$ components of the Einstein field equation and the time factor $f(t)$ can be absorbed in a redefinition of the time coordinate $t$. Of course $B'\neq 1/A'$, one has to apply the derivative rule.

Comment: So what would the equation be for B’ ? Would it just be the derivative of B with respect to r ?

Comment: Yes primes denote derivatives with respect to r.

Comment: Thank you so much.